# Repeat a Procedure using Checkbox column in Datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Good Afternoon.

I have a question and I don't know if its already done or new. Is it possible to repeat a same procedure many times based on checked column in datagridview?

Here is the scenario

Before I have a Datagridview that has a 3 Columns named `ID`,`Name` and `Cash` everytime I will click a row the data will transfer in 3 Labels and after that I will put a number in textbox that will compute the cash before saving it in database.

Now here is my target I will add a `checkboxcolumn` on the start of datagridview next to `ID` and here is the next part Lets say i will check 2 rows. Is it possible that both of them will go in the same procedure? (Transfer to Labels the compute before saving to database one by one?)

This is what I tried so far

This is the code of transfering datagridview data in labels (under cellclick)

```
  Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        Label2.Text = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value
        Label3.Text = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value
        Label4.Text = DataGridView1.Item("ReflectedQty", i).Value
        Label5.Text = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value
        Label6.Text = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value
        Label7.Text = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value
        Label8.Text = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value
        Dim cell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0)
        DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn_Uncheck()
        cell.Value = True
        standard()
```

Here is the computation part (under private sub standard)

```
 Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("server=192.168.2.87;userid=root;password=****;database=inventory")
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("select StandardUOM,QtyPerUoM from item_master_list where ItemCode = '" & Label2.Text & "'", con)
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        con.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Label9.Text = reader.GetString("StandardUOM")
            Label10.Text = reader.GetString("QtyPerUoM")
        End While
```

Here is the saving part or transferring to database (button click)

```
  DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0)
        Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=192.168.2.87;database=inventory;userid=root;password=*****")
        Dim cmdinsert As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("insert into receiving (RINo,PONo,ItemCode,Description,QtyPack,PackUoM,UnitPrice,Total,Remarks,ExpiryDate,QtyStan,StanUoM,PCS) values ('" & frm_Add_Receiving_Items.TextBox1.Text & "','" & Label1.Text & "','" & Label2.Text & "','" & Label3.Text & "','" & Label11.Text & "','" & Label5.Text & "','" & Label6.Text & "','" & Label7.Text & "','" & Label8.Text & "','" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "','" & Label12.Text & "','" & Label9.Text & "','" & Label10.Text & "')", con1)
        con1.Open()
        cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con1.Close()
```

[image]

Here is the output of the code

[image]

I hope I clear my question.

TYSM for future help

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far if I may ask? It is a good practice here to include your trial and errors so we will know where to help you.

Comment: Hello, TYSM for nice approach actualy what i tried so far is the transfering and the saving codes if you want to see that I will edit my post, kindly wait for a moment :)

Comment: @CrushSundae sir pls see the edited post

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente I would advise to remove the password from your connection string when posting. Not needed and could cause issues for you.

Comment: @CrushSundae have you seen it? I already edited it

Comment: @CrushSundae Sorry and TY for remider, Sir what do u think the cide for it?

Comment: Okay, the idea is on every click event, you compute the total based on each row that is checked. Then on clicking another button, all the checked rows will be saved to the database. Is that right?

Comment: @CrushSundae your right :)

Comment: What do you mean by transfer to labels? It will be like a list? For example you clicked 2 items. Those 2 items will appear in the label?

Comment: Or simply, you just want to save all records that are checked in the datagrid?

Comment: How I wish I will only checked the data in datagridview. What I mean is that the transfered data in label will change everytime based on how may icheck. I will edit my post and see the picture I will attach

Comment: @CrushSundae so we both correct but still you did not get back the down vote in my answer. Maybe you should be fair :) i was just trying to help others.

Comment: @Muj I upvote your answer and soon it will be approved :D

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente try my new update

Comment: @Muj currently trying Im having an operation now hahah

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente ok ok. just inform me if it works fine

Comment: @Muj sure TY TY

Comment: @Muj it works but the data has been repeated

Comment: @Muj please see the edited post

Comment: @CrushSundae please see the edited post

Comment: Okay, now I know what u really want. I'll answer it tomorrow since I'm already out of the office. That's if @Muj haven't got the correct answer yet.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Hmm in the last image that is the output of `done selecting multiple items` then the next in that is processing it and so on?

Comment: @Hi sir I only showed the output the when clicking the row and Im targetting to put a button multiple select and thats what will happen to the next data that will be checked. Sorry for late reply also

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente, kindly check if the answer I provided suffice what your are trying to do.

Comment: @Im currently testing it sir. I will update once im done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the `Comments` I placed in this code carefully so you'll understand what's going on.

I already included here the code for `CellClick` (which I replaced with `CellValueChanged` and the code for saving **only the checked rows**.

You can call `SaveCheckedRecords()` in one of your `button_Clicks`.

I also included a *Bonus* code that compute for *Unit Price* 's total .

```
Sub DataGridView1_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged( _
ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged
    If DataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty Then
        DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then 'SO THAT CHECKBOX COLUMN WILL ONLY TRIGGER THE CHANGES

        'THIS WILL HOLD THE VALUE OF THE CHECKBOX (TRUE OR FALSE)
        Dim currCheckCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = _
          CType(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)

        'LABEL CHANGES BASED ON THE ROW OF THE CHECKBOX
        'IF-CONDITION SO THAT LABEL CHANGES WILL HAPPEN ONLY IF THE CHECKBOX IS CHECKED
        If currCheckCell.Value = True Then
            Dim i As Integer = e.RowIndex
            Label2.Text = DataGridView1.Item("ItemCode", i).Value
            Label3.Text = DataGridView1.Item("Description", i).Value
            Label4.Text = DataGridView1.Item("ReflectedQty", i).Value
            Label5.Text = DataGridView1.Item("UOM", i).Value
            Label6.Text = DataGridView1.Item("UnitPrice", i).Value
            Label7.Text = DataGridView1.Item("Total", i).Value
            Label8.Text = DataGridView1.Item("Remarks", i).Value
        End If

        Standard()

        Dim totalstr As Double = 0
        For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
            Dim checkCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = _
           CType(drow.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
            If checkCell.Value = True Then
                totalstr += Val(drow.Cells(5).Value)
            End If
        Next
        lblTotal.Text = FormatNumber(totalstr, 2)
    End If
End Sub


Public Sub SaveCheckedRecords()
    DataGridView1.Columns.RemoveAt(0)
    Dim con1 As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("datasource=192.168.2.87;database=inventory;userid=root;password=*****")
    Dim cmdinsert As MySqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    For Each drow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        Dim checkCell As DataGridViewCheckBoxCell = _
       CType(drow.Cells(0), DataGridViewCheckBoxCell)
        If checkCell.Value = True Then 'AGAIN, TO CHECK IF THE COLUMN IS CHECKED
            'CELL INDEXES ARE ASSUMED SINCE YOU DIDN'T SPECIFIED IT ALSO
            'YOU ARE THE ONE WHO KNOWS THE RIGHT INDECES SO CHANGE THEM IF THE INDECES ARE WRONG
            Dim ItemCode As String = drow.Cells(1).Value
            Dim Desc As String = drow.Cells(2).Value
            Dim ReflectedQty As String = drow.Cells(3).Value
            Dim UOM As String = drow.Cells(4).Value
            Dim UnitPrice As Double = Val(drow.Cells(5).Value)
            Dim Total As Double = Val(drow.Cells(6).Value)
            Dim Remarks As String = drow.Cells(7).Value
            'NOW USE ALL OF THE VARIABLES ABOVE IN YOUR INSERT QUERY

            'CMDINSERT PART HERE SINCE I DON'T KNOW SOME OF YOUR LABELS 
            'LIKE LABEL11 SO IT'S UP TO YOU TO CREATE THE COMMAND WHICH IS EASY
            con1.Open()
            cmdinsert.ExecuteNonQuery()
            con1.Close()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

If there are errors (as I haven't tested the code) or things that you still don't understand, just comment it here .

Comment: Sir I will approve this because its working now :) and also +1 for @Muj

Comment: Sir by the way if its okay with you I will edit this based on my system so I can give you a 100 % clear explanation from head to toe Is that okay with you? I will update this today TYSSSSSSM

Comment: You can edit the answer as long as the _sense_ of the answer is not lost. Besides, some of the `indeces` and `variables` in my answer are based on assumptions since some of the details are not present in your post.

Comment: Thank you for the tip I will guarantee you to give the full details you want

Answer (score 0):

Try using loop.

Example

```
for each row as datagridviewrow in dg.rows
 if row.cell(NameOfChckbox).value = 'True' then
  'Transfer dg data to to label
  'insert your computation/call it
  'save to database
 end if
next
```

Hope this is what you want. if something is missing in my answer or not clear just inform me :)

----- ADVICE ------

some advice in my answer. this is not suitable in cellclick. because user sometime commit mistake like wrong click or thinking to much before clicking so i suggest after clicking in multiple checkbox in dg use a button to call this function.

------ LATEST UPDATE ------

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
 for each row as datagridviewrow in dg.rows
  if row.cell("NameOfChckboxCell").value = "True" then
   label1.text = row.cells("ItemCode").value
   etc . . .
   then call your standard sub?
   standard()
   then your save here. . .
  end if
End Sub
```

Maybe this is it? try it sir

Comment: @CrushSundae both of you are correct to make it more clear I want to explain something like this. lets say I have 5 rows with checkbox and I check 3 rows so what I want to happen is find the first checkbox,get its value,compute it and save it to database and Find the second checkbox do the same procedure as the first one find the third and so one. something like that sorry for late response looking forward for a good answer although Muj has some point.

Comment: @Muj please see the comment above this one

Comment: @Muj I upvote your answer so it will become neutral because i know how it feels to be downvoted even if your trying to help. I will mark this as answer if theres a changes that will work TYSM

Comment: @PaulEdwardPagente Sorry for late reply but i think my answer is almost there. hmm wait. what is the thing that you don't understand or misplace in my answer?

Comment: @Please see the edited post and TYSM for the answer cant wait to try it :D

Comment: I already removed the downvote to @Muj since the quality of his answer has improved since his last post.